# How to set the assembly strong name while creating SharePoint 2013 web services.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint-2013

While creating SharePoint 2013 web services I have added SharePoint layouts Mapped folder to project and again I have added Text file with extension **.asmx** to mapped folder in that asmx file added web services class.Problem here is I'm unable to set the "**Assembly strong name**". Could you please help me on this anyone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command 'sn' from VisualStudio prompt command.

This is the msdn link about assembly strong Name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You have to pass by these steps
1- Open the visual studio  prompt cmd change the location to theDLL's location.

2-Create the il file by this cmd.

  location> ildasm /all /out=dllName.il dllName.dll .
i think il means ' Inermediate Langage'

3-Generate the sn key to sign dll.

  location> sn -k mykey.snk

4- use ilasm command .

  location> ilasm /dll /key=mykey.snk dllName.il

Comment: That level of detail belongs in the question, so it is more visible to others. (Not everyone reads comments).

Answer (score 0):

First Open Visual Studio and Open the Solution/Project for which you want to get the strong name.

Go to Tools –> External Tools

[image: Add New Tool to generate Strong Name]

Click on "Add" to add a tool, and put in the following values:

```
Title: GetStrongName
Command: Powershell.exe
Arguments: -command "[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName(\"$(TargetPath)\").FullName"
```

Check "Use Output Window". All other checkboxes must be unchecked.
Click OK to Save.

[image: External Tools Dialog]

The new tool appears under Tools –> Get Qualified Assembly Name.

[image: Newly Created Tool]

When this menu item is selected, the assembly name is given in the output window.

It should look like

> YourWebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9eb90a69d4f49974